# batch file to append file names to end of lines

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory of files and I need to loop through the files, outputting the content of each file to a new file while appending the filename to the end of each line.

So from a directory of 10 files I want to end up with 1 file made up of the contents of each file but with each filename on the end of each line so i know which file it originaly came from.

I can append fixed text to the end of each line but I can't work out how to use the file name and also change it to work for any file. I've tried using a wildcard((%~dp0*.csv) but it says it cant find the file specified.

This is what I have so far:

```
for /F "delims=" %%j in (%~dp0\6691_706.csv) do echo.%%jAddToEndofLine >> %~dp0\New.txt
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It fails, as FOR /F doesn't allow wildcards for files, it is intended for reading a file line by line.
You should use the "normal" FOR

```
for %%A in (%~dp0\*.bat) do (
  echo Processing file '%%A'
  FOR /F "delims=" %%L in (%%A) do (
    echo Line %%L from file %%A >> %~dp0\New.txt
  )
)
```