# Get file name and append to beginning of line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get a side-by-side file path and file name in a text file so I can make inserting into a database easier.  I've taken a look at other examples around SO, but I haven't been able to understand what is going on.  For instance, I saw this [batch file to append file names to end of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847889/batch-file-to-append-file-names-to-end-of-lines) but figured that I shouldn't ask for clarification because it's 1.5 years old.

What I have is a text file of file paths.  They look like this:

`\\proe\igi_files\TIFFS\AD\1_SIZE_AD\1AD0019.tif`

What I want it to look like is this:

`1AD0019.tif \\proe\igi_files\TIFFS\AD\1_SIZE_AD\1AD0019.tif`

so that I can insert it into a database.  Is there an easy way to do this on Windows via Batch files?

Comment: What are you using to write the batch file?  Are you using Powershell?  Or, is this a DOS .bat file? Or, something else?  This can be done quite easily in Powershell.

Comment: I was using the DOS .bat style because that's what I know.  If it can be done easier in Powershell, then I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell, this little script should do the trick.  In the first line, just specify the name of the text file that contains all the file paths.

```
$filelist="c:\temp\filelist.txt"
foreach($L in Get-Content $filelist) {                      
  $i = $L.length - $L.lastindexof('\') -1
  $fname=$L.substring($L.length - $i, $i)  
  echo ($fname + ' ' + $L)
}
```

If you don't have powershell installed on your machine, check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx.

Comment: Worked like a charm, and ran really quick.

Comment: Cool!  Powershell is really handy for this kind of thing.  Thanks for the `answer`.

Answer (score 2):

No batch file required. From the command line:

```
>"outputFile.txt" (for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %F in ("inputFile.txt") do @echo %~nxF %~dpF)
```

But that output format is risky because file and folder names can contain spaces, so it may be difficult to determine where the file name ends and the path begins. Better to enclose the file and path within quotes.

```
>"outputFile.txt" (for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %F in ("inputFile.txt") do echo "%~nxF" "%~dpF")
```

if done within a batch file, then percents must be doubled.

```
@echo off
>"outputFile.txt" (
  for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%F in ("inputFile.txt") do echo "%%~nxF" "%%~dpF"
)
```

You should read the built in help for the FOR command. Type `help for` or `for /?` from a command prompt to get help. That strategy works for pretty much for all commands.

Comment: Still running the second one.  Can't tell if it's hung up somewhere, but the PowerShell solution ran quicker, so I gave the `Answer` status to @mti2935.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (yourfile.txt) DO ECHO %%~nxi %%i
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

No big drama - all on one active line, but spaced for clarity

Comment: Didn't quite work.  It only put `yourfile.txt` into the newfile.  It didn't actually parse the file paths inside of the `yourfile.txt`.

Comment: @Kruug do not put `yourfile.txt` in double quotes `""`. Take the code as it is.